# choosing the best combination of input values to a model in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to optimize a model that I've written in R.

I can run the model with the following:

```
mod <- run_model(data,md,s1,s2,s3)
```

where md,s1,s2,s3 are numerical values that are used to define specific parameters in the model. The question that I have is: is it possible in R to select the best combination of md, s1, s2 and s3 to drive the model. Specifically, i know that these variables should be one of the following

```
md <- c(1, 0.75, 0.5, 1.5, 0.3, 2.5)
s1 <- c(0.6,0.8)
s2 <- c(0.3,0.4,0.6)
s3 <- c(0.17336, 0.18246, 0.1921, 0.22624, 0.28704, 0.33518,
        0.5534, 0.7442, 1.019, 1.5122)
```

but I would like to know how to reduce the model error by selecting the best combination of these values.

So, if the error is defined by

```
err = observed - mod
```

how can I select the best possible combination of these input partameters to get the lowest err?

I was thinking that this might be possible in a loop (i.e. 4 different loops) but that idea does not sound very efficient. I was wondering if someone else had some suggestions as to what I should do? Note that I cannot use optim here because I don't wantto be told what the input value shold be, but to select the best value from the vectors provided. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What package is `run_model` from?

Comment: run_model is not from a package. It's an example (not actually called that) of a function I have that I wish to find the best input variables for. I will look into step

Comment: `apply(X = expand.grid(s1, s2, s3, md), MARGIN = 1, FUN = run_model)` Make sure `run_model` takes in one argument, a vector with 4 values and returns the `err` you wish to minimize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be easier to answer with a specific `run_model` function. But since you want to test a discrete set of parameter values for an arbitrary function with no assumptions about its form, you really need to test each combination to find the maximum.

You can create a data.frame of all possible input parameters with

```
pp <- expand.grid(md=md, s1=s1, s2=s2, s3=s3)
```

It would also be best if `run_model` were vectorized over all it's parameters. If it's not in its current form, you can use `Vectorize()` to help. I'm going to assume that `run_model` returns the overall error for a given parameter combination. Then you can do

```
# make all parameters vectorized (except for the first "data" parameter)
V_run_model <- Vectorize(run_model, vectorize.args = names(formals(run_model))[-1])
# get error values
err <- with(pp, V_run_model(data, md, s1, s2, s3))
# find best parameters (minimal error)
pp[which.min(err), ]
```